# Set numpy array elements to zero if they are above a specific threshold

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say, I have a numpy array consists of `10` elements, for example:

`a = np.array([2, 23, 15, 7, 9, 11, 17, 19, 5, 3])`

Now I want to efficiently set all `a` values higher than `10` to `0`, so I'll get:

`[2, 0, 0, 7, 9, 0, 0, 0, 5, 3]`

Because I currently use a `for` loop, which is very slow:

```
# Zero values below "threshold value".
def flat_values(sig, tv):
    """
    :param sig: signal.
    :param tv: threshold value.
    :return:
    """
    for i in np.arange(np.size(sig)):
        if sig[i] < tv:
            sig[i] = 0
    return sig
```

How can I achieve that in the most efficient way, having in mind big arrays of, say, `10^6` elements?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Generally, list comprehensions are faster than `for` loops in python (because python knows that it doesn't need to care for a lot of things that might happen in a regular `for` loop):

```
a = [0 if a_ > thresh else a_ for a_ in a]
```

but, as @unutbu correctly [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28430952/4433386), numpy allows list indexing, and element-wise comparison giving you index lists, so:

```
super_threshold_indices = a > thresh
a[super_threshold_indices] = 0
```

would be even faster.

Generally, when applying methods on vectors of data, have a look at `numpy.ufuncs`, which often perform much better than python functions that you map using any native mechanism.

Comment: You need an else in your statement:
a = [0 if a_ > thresh else a_ for a_ in a]

Comment: @ben26941 true dat. Um, surprising nobody noticed so far.

Comment: For non-destructive operation, see [abda01](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58872295/774575)

Answer (score 172):

```
In [7]: a = np.array([2, 23, 15, 7, 9, 11, 17, 19, 5, 3])

In [8]: a[a > 10] = 0

In [9]: a
Out[9]: array([2, 0, 0, 7, 9, 0, 0, 0, 5, 3])
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Note that if you happen to care about the absolute value of the element you can use: a[np.abs(a) > 10] = 0

Comment: Is there a way to combine multiple (say, 5) conditionals?

Comment: @BrysonS. Write a separate function that contains your 5 conditionals and returns a boolean value. You can then use it like this:  `a[my_validation_func(a)] = 0`

Comment: @AlexHall could you show how the return of **my_validation_func(a)** would look like?

Answer (score 27):

If you don't want to change your original array

```
In [2]: a = np.array([2, 23, 15, 7, 9, 11, 17, 19, 5, 3])
      
In [3]: b = np.where(a > 10, 0, a)

In [4]: b
Out[4]: array([2, 0, 0, 7, 9, 0, 0, 0, 5, 3])

In [5]: a
Out[5]: array([ 2, 23, 15,  7,  9, 11, 17, 19,  5,  3])
```

Answer (score 1):

From the neural networks from scratch series by sentdex on Youtube, he used `np.maximum(0, [your array])` to make all values less than 0 into 0.

For your question I tried `np.minimum(10, [your array])` and it seemed to work incredibly fast. I even did it on an array that was 10e6 (uniform distribution generated using `50 * np.random.rand(10000000)`), and it worked in 0.039571 seconds. I hope this is fast enough.

Comment: That replaces them by 10, not by 0