# Return True/False for entire array if any value meets mask requirement(s)

Tags: python

I have already tried looking at other similar posts however, their solutions do not solve this specific issue. Using the answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28430904/set-numpy-array-elements-to-zero-if-they-are-above-a-specific-threshold) I found that I get the error: "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()" because I define my array differently from theirs. Their array is a size (n,) while my array is a size (n,m). Moreover, the solution from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-list) does not work either because it applies to lists. The only method I could think of was this:

When there is at least 1 True in array, then entire array is considered True:

```
filt = 4
tracktruth = list()
arraytruth = list()
arr1 = np.array([[1,2,4]])
for track in range(0,arr1.size):
    if filt == arr1[0,track]:
        tracktruth.append(True)
    else:
        tracktruth.append(False)

if any(tracktruth):
    arraytruth.append(True)
else:
    arraytruth.append(False)
```

When there is not a single True in array, then entire array is considered False:

```
filt = 5
tracktruth = list()
arraytruth = list()
arr1 = np.array([[1,2,4]])
for track in range(0,arr1.size):
    if filt == arr1[0,track]:
        tracktruth.append(True)
    else:
        tracktruth.append(False)

if any(tracktruth):
    arraytruth.append(True)
else:
    arraytruth.append(False)
```

The reason the second if-else statement is there is because I wish to apply this mask to multiple arrays and ultimately create a master list that describes which arrays are true and which are false in their entirety. However, with a for loop and two if-else statements, I think this would be very slow with larger arrays. What would be a faster way to do this?

Comment: So you just want to check whether value is in nested array?

Comment: What's an example where `.any()` doesn't give you the result you want?

Comment: @pierogi I edited my original post for clarity. I want to see if there are any values that are less than the defined numerical value.

Comment: @HeapOverflow I edited the original post to show both instances.

Comment: I still don't really see test data. I see a bunch of code (and it's not clear whether it's correct), but I don't really see what's the the input data and what's the desired output data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems overly complicated, you can use boolean indexing to achieve results without loops

```
arr1=np.array([[1,2,4]])

filt=4

arr1==filt

array([[False, False,  True]])

np.sum(arr1==filt).astype(bool)

True
```

With nmore than one row, you can use the row or column index in the `np.sum` or you can use the `axis` parameter to sum on rows or columns

As pointed out in the comments, you can use `np.any()` instead of the `np.sum(...).astype(bool)` and it runs in roughly 2/3 the time on the test dataset:

```
np.any(a==filt, axis=1)

array([ True])
```

Comment: Very simple and cool method. Pretty much just needs two lines. I did not know one could add logic that way.

Comment: Vectorization of operations is really where numpy shines. While there are _some_ cases where you need to loop in numpy, they're really more edge-cases than the norm. Cheers!

Comment: Does this differ from `(arr1 == filt).any()`?

Comment: Good call, edited. I used `np.any()` instead of `array.any()` to match the rest of my answer, but the same principal applies

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with list comprehension. I've done it here for one array but it's easily extended to multiple arrays with a for loop

```
filt = 4
arr1 = np.array([[1,2,4]])
print(any([part == filt for part in arr1[0]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `arraytruth` more generally, with list comprehension for the array of size (n,m)

```
import numpy as np

filt = 4
a = np.array([[1, 2, 4]])
b = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [5, 6, 7]])

array_lists = [a, b]

arraytruth = [True if a[a==filt].size>0 else False for a in array_lists]

print(arraytruth)
```

This will give you:

```
[True, False]
```

Answer (score 1):

[edit] Use numpy hstack method.

```py
filt = 4
arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3]])

print(any([x for x in np.hstack(arr) if x < filt]))
```